# Can I use metal knockout for additional NM cable?

Tags: wiring, junction-box, recessed-lighting

[image: junction box]

My can light junction box has 2 black clamps for NM cables and there are 3 metal knockout holes on 3 sides of junction box. (Picture shows one of these 3 knockouts).

Given the location of LINE wire and can light locations in celling, can I attach 3 NM (romex) cables with one can light ? Can light junction box has only 2 clamps , but can I use knockout hole ( metal) for 3rd cable? All cables are NM cables

1 LINE cable (through Knockout holes)

2 cables connecting to 2 other can lights. ( Through black clamps)

Take a look at diagram with red color can in question.

[image]

Comment: Is that box marked with a volume (cubic inches) anywhere?

Comment: I agree, I know the problem seems "solved" to you OP, but the "cubic inch" question is important, and may be a deal-killer.  We need to know.

Comment: It does say max 8 14 AWG conductors on junction box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use something when ever NM cable enters a metal box or enclosure to protect the cable from abrasion.

If you use a clamp for two cables, it must be rated for two cables of the applicable size.
For example the Arlington NM94 is made for a 1/2" trade size knockout and can be used with one or two 14/2 or 12/2 NM cables.

[image: Arlington NM94]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to add an appropriate clamp, like:

[image: NM clamp]

You should be able to get them at any hardware store/home improvement big box store/etc. An electrical supply house will be cheaper, but for an occasional clamp just go "anywhere".

Comment: I have one like this one already. Would it work ? Check out link. https://tinyurl.com/y5hyk7sa

Comment: That's a different style but perfectly fine.  The only question is whether it matches the knockout size.

Comment: @user2716454 Yes, that clamp indicates it is meant for this purpose (securing NM-B cable in 1/2 knockout).

Comment: I am pretty sure the clamp in the picture is actually rated for just one cable.

Comment: @batsplatsterson I figured that was the case. My understanding was that OP's fixture had two integral clamps and needed a third one.

Comment: @batsplatsterson Just read the question again: "can I use knockout hole ( metal) for 3rd cable" So my answer works. That being said, sometimes it is easier if the cables all enter through the same location, so your answer is good too.